# Convert array data into a string - reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, tostring

I have an array with several objects in it. To show you the structure of the array it is like this
[image]

```
0: {lat: "7.9511758", lon: "80.7426426"}
1: {lat: "6.9566662", lon: "80.7608237"}
2: {lat: "6.3872411", lon: "80.4952031"}
3: {lat: "5.9435367", lon: "80.4543506"}
4: {lat: "6.4543259", lon: "81.5608547"}
5: {lat: "7.8554038", lon: "80.6491562"}
6: {lat: "6.8556687", lon: "81.0505434"}
7: {lat: "7.293609", lon: "80.6391363"}
8: {lat: "6.802641", lon: "80.7899271"}
9: {lat: "8.3351457", lon: "80.3332731"}
10: {lat: "6.0237174", lon: "80.2153073"}
11: {lat: "7.9341074", lon: "80.943138"}
12: {lat: "7.9317005", lon: "81.5589219"}
13: {lat: "6.8377508", lon: "81.8086608"}
```

I want to create a string using the data of this array. I need to create a string that looks like this.
My data is stored in a state as `this.state.destinationLocation`

```
7.9511758,80.7426426|6.9566662,80.7608237|6.3872411,80.4952031|.....
```

How can i achieve this result?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Also, it's nice to provide volunteers sample data as text so they don't have to transcribe data from a picture...

Answer (score 7):

You can use `reduce`

```
const stringData = data.reduce((result, item) => {
  return `${result}${item.lat},${item.lon}|`
}, "")

console.log(stringData)
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
yourArray.map(({lat, lon}) => `${lat},${lon}`).join('|');
```

Also see [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter) and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Giving upvote! I like this solution even better than `reduce()` approach, as it is more declarative and at the same time simpler / needs less code.

Answer (score 3):

I think `Array.reduce` method is the way to go.

```js
const array = [{lat: "1", lon: "2"},{lat: "3", lon: "4"} ]

const reducedArray = array.reduce((acc, curr) => `${acc}${curr.lat},${curr.lon}|` ,'')

console.log(reducedArray)
```

Working JS Bin example: https://jsbin.com/jawiziduxo/edit?js,console,output

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would suggest:

```
const myString = myArray.reduce((accumulator, item) =>
accumulator ? `${accumulator}|${item.lat},${item.lon}` : `${item.lat},${item.lon}`, null);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: This should be the least erroneous and the most reliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just iterate through the entries and append into a string..

Here's a pseudo-code of what you need to do

```
set string to empty
for each entry in array
    append lat, comma, lng, pipe
repeat
```

Then you would have `string` variable containing what you need.

Answer (score 0):

We can do something like this:

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { lat: "3.23434234", lon: "233.46353252" },
        { lat: "3.23434234", lon: "233.46353252" },
        { lat: "3.23434234", lon: "233.46353252" },
        { lat: "3.23434234", lon: "233.46353252" },
        { lat: "3.23434234", lon: "233.46353252" }
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    let { data } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {data.map(data => {
          return `${data.lat},${data.lon}|`;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Here is the working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rgb68hcj/1/)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: [How do I create a React Stack Snippet with JSX support?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537)